# Как в цикл передать переменную c номером ul, чтобы из него вывелось одно значение в нужный ul

Tags: jquery, each

Есть некий цикл, в котором крутится три значения из output

```
const { output } = JSON.parse(response);
$('.hs-categ').each(function (i) {
        var pagcat = $(this).find('.pagcat');
        output[i].forEach(function (page) //перебор и вывод
        {
            const pag = getItemPAG(page);
            pagcat.empty().append(pag); //очищаем старую и добавляем новую выборку
        });
});

function getItemPAG(page)
{
    const pagHTML = `
        <div id="pagelink">${page}</div>`;

    return pagHTML;
}
```

Затем эти три значения отравляются в ul

```
<div class="hs-categ"><?= $cat[0] ?>
   <ul class="pagcat">
 
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="hs-categ"><?= $cat[1] ?>
   <ul class="pagcat">
 
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="hs-categ"><?= $cat[2] ?>
   <ul class="pagcat">
 
   </ul>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что когда я хочу с помощью ajax прогнать по этому же циклу одно значение и отправить **например в третий** по счету блок, то это значение **попадает в первый блок**.
Я пытался доработать цикл и с помощью переменной **var arr = 3;** (число будет меняться мной в зависимости от нумерации блока ul) дать понять циклу в какой блок вывести единственное значение output, которое там крутится.

```
$('.hs-categ').each(function (i) {
        var arr = 3;
        var pagcat = $(this).find('.pagcat');
        output[i].forEach(arr, function (page, e) //перебор и вывод
        {
            const pag = getItemPAG(page);
            pagcat.empty().eq(e).append(pag); //очищаем старую и добавляем новую выборку
        });
});
```

Как можно вывести единственное значение из цикла в блок так, чтобы значение попадало в ul, нумерацию которого я укажу в **var arr = 3;**?

Comment: обернуть циклы в функцию, аргумент которой и будет индекс куда вставлять и в начале проверять индекс `if (arr !== i+1) return;`; или переделать получше)

Comment: InDevX, но у меня уже вставляются значения в блоки внутри цикла. Как я смогу вынести это в функцию?

Comment: В смысле? Вы поняли что значит вынести в функцию?

Comment: InDevX, понял. Просто мне не очень нравится такое решение проблемы. Я думал можно как-то сам цикл оптимизировать

Comment: т.е скинуть вам пример всего кода? Там довольно много. Я могу отправить весь js код, который участвует в вводе\выводе данных. Давайте я покажу пример как я решил проблему с помощью функций, но мне это не очень нравится. Некрасиво получилось

Comment: в js приходит только этот банальный и упрощенный пример Array
(
    [0] => 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
) Не знаю как тут в личку отправлять

Comment: мне пришлось добавить новую функцию function renderOneCategory(response) чтобы повторить всё сначала. Очень некрасиво(

Comment: yandex не открываю принципиально) добавил пример в ответ, вызывать функцию сколько угодно раз можно и где угодно, будет перезаписывать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const output = [[1],[2],[3]];

function writePages(pageIndex) {
  $('.hs-categ .pagcat').each(function (i) {
    if (pageIndex && pageIndex !== i+1) return;
    output[i].forEach(page => {
      $(this).empty().append(`<div id="pagelink">${page}</div>`);
      // id не должен дублироваться ---------^
    });
  });
}


writePages();
// записать конкретный блок:
// writePages(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hs-categ">
   <ul class="pagcat">
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="hs-categ">
   <ul class="pagcat">
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="hs-categ">
   <ul class="pagcat">
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: в том то и дело, что id у меня и дублируется и нет в зависимости от того вывожу я все пагинации или только одну. Придется так же дублировать функцию))

Comment: не понял.. зачем функцию дублировать? дублируется только id="pagelink", но это исправить не трудно

Comment: ` // id не должен дублироваться ---------^` чтобы это обойти. Может показать тогда код на гугл диске лучше?)

Comment: А зачем он вообще нужен? id этот, можно и на гугл диске (github для такого дела лучший вар-т)

Comment: https://github.com/inDevX доступ на этот акк нужен) приватный репо

Comment: допилил вывод отдельных категорий. Оказывается там нумерация блоков идет начиная с 1. Из-за этого не работало. Ответ можно считать правильным если правильно нумеровать блоки, в которые хочется вывести)